# Remove components from DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I have a component which push components to DOM dynamically. 
However, I need to remove old components from my DOM whenever I push new set of components. Everything on Angular 2. :)

It works if I remove one component but if I try to remove array of components it won’t work. Insertion is work properly but removing is not. 
Find the code segment below,

```
let resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);

    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedInputs, this.dynamicComponentContainer.parentInjector);

    for(let t of data){


        //create a factory out of the component we want to create
        let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(t.component);


        //create the component using the factory and the injector
        var component = factory.create(injector);

        this.currentComponent.push(component);
        // Insert the component into the dom container
        this.dynamicComponentContainer.insert(component.hostView);



    }

    if (this.previousComponent) {

            for(let comp of this.previousComponent){
                comp.destroy();
            }
        }

    this.previousComponent = this.currentComponent;
```

Any idea .. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is re-init  `this.currentComponent`:

`this.currentComponent = [];` before `for(let t of data)`

**[WORKING DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/SSVrh1cHgjmK7YaJ7VFu?p=preview)**